# How to write tabbed form in html

Tags: html, forms, tabbed

Referring to [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp) on how to create a tabbed form in html: the example works as expected until you embed the code within a `<form>` element. Then clicking the tabs causes a form submission, and in the case of the example, an error.

Does anyone know a way out of this?

Comment: Can you share some code for what you tried?

Comment: Click the link above, and then click "Try it Yourself". Try clicking the tabs on the right. Then edit the code so the entire "form" is inside a <form></form> and try again.

Comment: <p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<form action="">
<div class="tab">
...
</div>
</form>

<script>
...

Comment: What error or behavior are you seeing?

Answer (score 2):

In the example you submit section there is a function called OpenCity that passes a event. To stop it from refreshing or submitting you just have to prevent the default state:

```
<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {

   evt.preventDefault();

   ...
}
</script>
```

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
 
    evt.preventDefault();

  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.button {
  padding:15px;
  border: none 0px white;
  border-color: white;
  background-color: #318DE8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<h2>Tabs</h2>
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<form>
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  <input name="value_1" value="" placeholder="Insert Value that will remain when switched"/>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
  <input name="value_2" value="" placeholder="Insert Value that will remain when switched"/>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
  <input name="value_3" value="" placeholder="Insert Value that will remain when switched"/>
</div>
<br>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>


   
</body>
</html>
```